# Pandas concat dataframe row seem index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe and I will concat but just row will have the seem index

my first dataframe look like this

```
               a         b         c         d         e         f 
20018-01-05  1.702556 -0.885554  0.766257 -0.731700 -1.071232  1.806680   
20018-01-06 -0.968689 -0.700311  1.024988 -0.705764  0.804285 -0.337177   
20018-01-07  1.249893 -0.613356  1.975736 -0.093838  0.428004  0.634204   
20018-01-08  0.430000  0.502100  0.194092  0.588685 -0.507332  1.404635   
20018-01-09  1.005721  0.604771 -2.296667  0.157201  1.583537  1.359332
```

and i will concat this dataframe

```
               g         h         
20018-01-05  13.702556 -03.885554      
20018-01-06 -03.968689 -03.700311   
20018-01-07  13.249893 -03.613356   
20018-01-22  03.430000  03.502100    
20018-01-23  13.005721  03.604771
```

I would like concat just the tree first line with the seem index in drop others

my final dataframe should look like this

```
                     a         b         c         d         e         f          g          h
    20018-01-05  1.702556 -0.885554  0.766257 -0.731700 -1.071232  1.806680   13.702556 -03.885554
    20018-01-06 -0.968689 -0.700311  1.024988 -0.705764  0.804285 -0.337177  -03.968689 -03.700311 
    20018-01-07  1.249893 -0.613356  1.975736 -0.093838  0.428004  0.634204   13.249893 -03.613356
```

Comment: `df1.join(df2, how='inner')`

Comment: big thx it's works !

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
>>> pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1).ix[:2, 1:]
           a          b     ...               g           h
0   1.702556  -0.885554     ...       13.702556  -03.885554
1  -0.968689  -0.700311     ...      -03.968689  -03.700311
2   1.249893  -0.613356     ...       13.249893  -03.613356

[3 rows x 9 columns]
```